# doxygen todo list is losing/missing some todo comments

Tags: objective-c, ios, doxygen

I'm using doxygen within an Objective-C iOS project and it is not adding all of the `@todo` comments to the Todo List page.

All of the comments are of the form:

```
/** @todo Thing that needs to be done described here */
```

Out of about 20 in the project, only 5 show up in the Todo List page. I can't spot any obvious pattern except that all of the ones that *do* appear are in a "Member" section (some of the ones that don't appear are also in member functions but I can't figure out why they don't appear). I would expect that all `@todo` comments would show up in the Todo List regardless of where in the code they are.

**Update:**
I've been experimenting with a minimal class...

`TodoTestClass.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TodoTestClass : UIViewController

- (void)someMethod;
- (void)otherMethod;

/** @todo add a method to do foo */

@end
```

`TodoTestClass.m`:

```
#import "TodoTestClass.h"

@implementation TodoTestClass

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    /** @todo do stuff here */
}

- (void)someMethod
{
    /** @todo document and implement someMethod */
}

/**
 This does some other stuff
 */
- (void)otherMethod
{
    /** @todo implement otherMethod */
}

@end
```

The `@todo` comment in the header and the one in `viewDidLoad` don't appear in the Todo List, but the other two do. If I remove the declarations of `someMethod` and `otherMethod` from the header, none of them appear. So `@todo` comments in undocumented methods (including methods overridden from undocumented frameworks), private methods, and general `@todo` comments that don't relate to a specific documented entity don't get added to the Todo List - just as user 'doxygen' mentioned in comments (thanks).

However, now that I understand *why* some `@todo` comments are not appearing, my desire for a complete Todo List and my question still remain...

Is there any way to configure doxygen so that it adds all `@todo` comments regardless of where they are to the Todo List?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of a case where the @todo item does not appear? Note that the todo items have to be part of the documentation of something (i.e. a member, interface, file, global variable, etc.). If you believe you found a bug it is better to submit a bug report in doxygen's bug tracker.

Comment: It's tricky to do as I can't see an obvious pattern, but I'll give it a go. I don't think it's a bug - it's probably that I don't understand how to use it properly. When you say it needs to be part of something's documentation, does that mean I can't just put todos in an otherwise undocumented function, such as `/** @todo Replace foo with bar in the line below once bar is working */` ?

Comment: @doxygen What I want to do doesn't seem possible at the moment, how do I add a feature request (rather than a bug)?

Answer (score 0):

try to place your comments before the code you want to target with your comment:

```
/** @todo add a method to do foo */ 
@interface TodoTestClass : UIViewController
```

and

```
/** @todo do stuff here */
- (void)viewDidLoad`
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comments within the code should be ignored.

Comment: The question is: "Is there any way to configure doxygen so that it adds all @todo comments regardless of where they are to the Todo List?"